How to make my magic system less pay to win?
In my story no one is born with magic but the can gain the right to use it via a job class ticket for a mage. There are different types, trees and ranks of jobs that an aspiring mage can get. If they are willing to spend lots of my world's currency to get a specific one, they can.
Here is where I am having a problem in my story: I feel like I made a pay to get stronger system. For example, my MC who is an Enchanter's student can enchant items with low probability of success, but he can upgrade to the better version Enchanter then intermediate Enchanter and then master Enchanter, or he can switch to different type of mage entirely with a new job class ticket.
If you are rich you can skip being a student or trainee and become a master instead at whatever magic the ticket gives you.
Is there a way to make it less of a pay to win system?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How can one earn this currency to buy the ticket? What is the limitation on the currency, or the system? What do you want to achieve by creating this system (aka, why do you create this pay to win system)? Can you use another system?

Not really an answer, but you can check pay2win games and learn how they limit power growth from purchases.

I’m a little confused by the question. You have invented/described a pay to win system, and are trying to figure out how to make it less pay to win? This feels like if I asked a question like, “how do I make my main character a less good swordsman” and then specifying that in my story I made him a master swordsman in your story. If you don’t want to pay to win system, why have you written one?

Your system is inherently pay to win. This does not need to be a problem if you write the right story to go with it. The fact is any magic system where someone needs to let another person in to access it will have some gatekeeping. In real life skills and education have this gatekeeping as well. We overcome these in many ways, some people cheat, lie, or steal to advance themselves. Some people develop skills or abilities on their own regardless of their circumstances in life, and yet others seek loans or free programs to gain the training they need.
If you want to keep the same magic system, where anyone can wield a magic, but someone must first let someone in to it my recommendations are these:

tie the giving of the magic to a physical object, a ticket, or contract, or something. This can make visible the bestowed contract and lets people engage in forgery and theft which can be great story elements.
make sure that people can with time and practice develop magical skills on their own. This would be how the first contracts/bestowals were first made and how new skills or abilities are discovered. Someone discovers them, codifies them, and sells the patented discovery.
Include private and state run charities, as well as community colleges, and limited magical contracts or visas (or loans). In the real world charities, community colleges, and private businesses offer training, resources, and opportunities with no or decreased expenses. They arent ever quite as high quality as the highest end things but some people have gone very far with very little.
Remember family will likely try to help people starting out in life out. They may have magical abilities, tricks or traditions that they can pass down to their kids. They probably wont be fancy but they might be useful in the right circumstances.

In the end your magic system mimics the same advantages and disadvantages of many things in the real world. Some people start with little, some people have small capacities, others start with tons or have incredible capacities. In many countries we try to balance opportunities even if many dont think its possible (or maybe even right) to try to balance outcomes, your fantasy civ will probably do the same.

Introduce some genetic or random aspect
Maybe some people simply get more out of magic, and the same ticket will get different people different amounts of power. Some wealthy individuals who lack their own magical talent might seek out less wealthy people, and sponsor them as personal servants. Most wealthy people are unlikely to want to get their hands dirty in the first place, so the more utilitarian of them wouldn't particularly care that the cost of the ticket would buy someone else power.
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
Risk or cost scales with power level
A lot of magic systems balance themselves by introducing a higher cost to the user for more powerful magic. Potentially, this could mean that each person has a finite amount of magic which either replenishes at a fixed rate, or which does not replenish at all, and the tier of their magical ability reflects the amount of power that a user can remove from their internal well at a single point in time.
You could also say that wielding greater power comes at the cost of control or risk to the user's wellbeing.
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
Magic above a certain level causes infertility
Much of wealth is inherited. If a wealthy person wishes to have a dynasty, they might consider avoiding the use of magical power to preserve their lineage. And really any disfigurement or cost of this scope could serve; generally, you want to avoid life altering consequences. This is sort of a combination of the previous ideas.
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
Magic has some similarities to drugs
Magic, assumed to be exposing the user to forces and senses beyond the typical human experience, would leave the normal world feeling gray and flat afterwards. The effect on the senses and the brain could easily justify some addictive properties or at least a sense of being smaller, i.e. withdrawal, once the magic use was over. Naturally, some wealthy people would live with this consequence, but a lot of them would draw the line and never expose themselves to magic above a certain level to preserve their ability to think and experience clearly outside of magic use. Depending, it could also have adverse impacts on the body, that's really up to you.
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
Overall
Just make sure that the use of magic has some cost to it, which the rich are unwilling to pay.

Where Do Tickets Come From?
You can buy "tickets" which give you magical skills, or upgrade your skills; they're very expensive, but anyone with the money can get one, right?  Does someone have the Ur-skill of making tickets?  What happens if he dies, or is kidnapped?  Or are tickets bestowed on the chosen by the gods, or fate, and then sold by greedy or needy "chosen" who don't have time or entrepreneurial initiative to develop a business around their shiny new skill?  Are there people out there who just keep the tickets bestowed on them, or bestow them as gifts to others?
Are tickets used up and gone when someone dies, or can you kill a mage and take their skills?
If tickets are made by someone with the Ur-skill to make tickets, does a nation / consortium of mages try to limit who this special wizard can sell to?  It would be dangerous to the world order if some wealthy nation decided to magic-up before starting a war.  Or if that upstart poor nation not appreciating our generous hegemony tried scraping together the money to buy magic to resist...  (And do governments invest worthy people with magic, in exchange for their agreeing to defend the country?  Do those granted skills ever then go rogue?)
If skills pass on upon death, can it be to someone the mage specified, instead of whoever was there at the scene of the death?  (Making friends with wizards could matter a great deal.)  Or do the tickets revert, to be sold again?  Are there an ultimately limited number of tickets?
Is magical effectiveness entirely a function of skills bought, or does actual experience play a part?  That is, will an expert craftsman with an enchanting skill, who's also studied and practiced enchanting, make better enchanted items, or will items be just as good made by the schlub who had a pile of tickets bestowed on him yesterday?  Will a knight, trained in body and mind, make better use of combat magic, and be potentially deadlier, than someone who bought twice as many ranks in fire magic?
Flesh out the finer mechanics of how the system works, then consider the implications

Subsidy and paid scholarships
In our current world we have pay to win. Schools and universities! You have many directions to choose from, learning trees and specialisations. Is it pay to win? That depends on the country. Though many are not.
With subsidies the money to be paid can be reduced to zero, or a manageable sum for most. The people who can't afford it can request special subsidies to make it manageable regardless. Higher education is often more expensive, requiring more money. You can still apply the same here.
Someone close to me went to a university where they didn't need to pay anything, because they had a certain high skill. I myself was in a different country and racked up quite some dept, but it is a dept you can pay off in quite some years if you get a job and diligently pay it off.
That is all thanks to subsidies so that people do not need to pay the price of a house for the uncertain promise of earning it back in your chosen work field (USA! USA!). Our job market offers more though. On the job learning, traineeships or full blown university level schooling, all paid by the businesses that (want to) employ you.
All this reduces the 'pay to win' aspect of magic. Just like the real world, it doesn't eliminate it in most cases. Having connections or wealthy friends and family can always give you a privileged position. You can make magic attainable for most of the population at least. With even the most unfortunate individuals having a chance to study the highest levels of magic available.
